# Firebase Content Security Policy changes in manifest

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase, manifest, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to access my firebase database through my chrome extension. 
I am continuously getting this :-

[image]

My manifest file has this line for content_security_policy-

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'".
```

**Edit-This is the error text:-**

Refused to frame 'https://*.firebaseapp.com/....
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src https://clients4.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/ https://calendar.google.com/accounts/ 'self' https://accounts.google.com/ https://apis.google.com/u/ https://apis.google.com/_/streamwidgets/ https://clients6.google.com/static/ https://content.googleapis.com/static/ https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/ https://www.google.com/calendar/ https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ https://docs.google.com/ https://drive.google.com https://*.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ https://feedback.googleusercontent.com/resources/ https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/ https://support.google.com/inapp/ https://*.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ifr https://hangouts.google.com/ https://talkgadget.google.com/ https://*.talkgadget.google.com/ https://www-gm-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ https://plus.google.com/ https://wallet.google.com/gmail/ https://www.youtube.com/embed/ https://clients5.google.com/pagead/drt/dn/ https://clients5.google.com/ads/measurement/jn/ https://www.gstatic.com/mail/ww/ https://www.gstatic.com/mail/intl/ https://clients5.google.com/webstore/wall/ https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/ https://apis.google.com/additnow/ https://www.gstatic.com/mail/promo/ https://notifications.google.com/ https://mail-payments.google.com/mail/payments/".

Refused to load the script 'https://...firebaseio.com/..... because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://clients4.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/ 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://mail.google.com/_/scs/mail-static/ https://hangouts.google.com/ https://talkgadget.google.com/ https://*.talkgadget.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/installedApps/ https://www-gm-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/js/ https://docs.google.com/static/doclist/client/js/ https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/ https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/ https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ [https://apis.google.com/*/scs/abc-static/*](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/) https://apis.google.com/js/ https://clients1.google.com/complete/ [https://apis.google.com//scs/apps-static/_/js/](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/) https://ssl.gstatic.com/inputtools/js/ https://ssl.gstatic.com/cloudsearch/static/o/js/ https://www.gstatic.com/feedback/js/ https://www.gstatic.com/common_sharing/static/client/js/ https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/".

I am trying to do remote injection to firebase database of this script. :-

```
var config = {
        apiKey: -----,
        authDomain: -----,
        databaseURL: ----,
        storageBucket: ----,
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      var dbRef=firebase.database().ref().child('text');
      $("#h1").on('keyup',function(){
         dbRef.set($("#h1").html());
      });
```

What should I do to tackle this error ?

Comment: Please include the actual error text, instead of a screenshot of an error message.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am trying to write the contents of compose window of gmail to firebase database. Can you help me out ? Would be really helpful to get a lead in my app. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Refused to load the script 'https://...firebaseio.com/..... because it violates the following Content Security Policy directiv

You should include the `firebase.js` script in your extension itself, instead of trying to load it from the public location.

Comment: I have included the firebase.js script successfully in my extension ,but when I am trying to initialise the database configuration this error keeps on popping in my console continuously.

Comment: The "Refused to load the script" should disappear if you've included the script in your extension and load it from there. If you have another error, post that.

Comment: It worked now, I added firebase.js as one of the content_scripts .Thanks a ton :)